# Connection refused on frankenphp laravel with mysql docker image

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, docker

I use frankenphp default docker-compose .yaml to develop on local with a bit MySQL database as an addition. but even though I have exposed the DB port, my laravel app still could not connect to the DB.

compose.yaml

```
# compose.yaml

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:8.1.0
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
  php:
    # uncomment the following line if you want to use a custom Dockerfile
    build: .
    # uncomment the following line if you want to run this in a production environment
    # restart: always
    ports:
      - "80:80" # HTTP
      - "443:443" # HTTPS
      - "443:443/udp" # HTTP/3
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
      - caddy_data:/data
      - caddy_config:/config
    depends_on:
      - db
    # comment the following line in production, it allows to have nice human-readable logs in dev
    tty: true

# Volumes needed for Caddy certificates and configuration
volumes:
  caddy_data:
  caddy_config:
```

.env

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laravel
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=root
```

is there's something I miss?

Comment: try to give the service a name like `container_name: database` and then in `.env` use that name on `DB_HOST=database`

Comment: if you use docker on VSC, you can inspect the db container, and search for `IPAddress` and put that on the `.env`

Answer (score 0):

You have two services in your `compose.yaml` file:

- `db`
- `php`

In this case, you should **use the service name** (`db`) instead of IP in the `DB_HOST` in `.env` file.

So, final look will be `DB_HOST=db`.

I'm not sure, but you also might need to add username and password under the `environment` in your `compose.yaml` file, like:

```
environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
```

Answer (score -1):

It's probably because you don't have the pdo_mysql extension installed in your container.

You will have to do something like this in your Dockerfile:

```
FROM dunglas/frankenphp

# add additional extensions here:
RUN install-php-extensions \
    pdo_mysql \
    gd \
    intl \
    zip \
    opcache
```